# Rotating a path for a CAAnimation

Tags: objective-c, path, rotation, caanimation

I'm animating some stuff using CAAnimation, & it involves making a fairly complex path using CGPathAddCurveToPoint, maybe 10 - 15 of these per path. Is there a way, instead of recalculating every curve, I could just rotate the whole path once it's built? I don't want to rotate the whole graphics context, as it's just the animation path which needs to change.

(I've tried putting a CGAffineTransformMakeRotation into every curve element, but that just has weird effects, it's like it's not rotating the path as a whole)

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a transform to the entire path, or to the drawing context.

See

```
- (void)applyTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
```

in  the `UIBezierPath` documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that - it's good to find I can manipulate the animation path once I've made it! I don't suppose you know how to change the anchor point for the rotation transform, that's got me stumped now... (I'll post another question if I can't find the answer)

Comment: Translate, rotate, translate again.  You can send -applyTransform: as many times as you want.